# Scaling of multiplot while using variables to define the column

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am getting data from a script `stuff.pl` and want to plot dynamically into one graph. So I am going to use a loop in Gnuplot (v4.6 patchlevel 3) which leads me to following problem:

Using the file `TEST.gp`:

```
xCol=2; yCol=3
set term x11 1
plot '< stuff.pl' u xCol:yCol

xCol=4; yCol=5
set term x11 1
set autoscale y
replot '< stuff.pl' u xCol:yCol

pause 1
```

and run it via `gnuplot TEST.gp` my graph isn't scaled proper. The plot is just showing the second graph (scales to its values).

If I use

```
plot '< stuff.pl' u 2:3
replot '< stuff.pl' u 4:5
```

, which should behave the same imo, the scaling works.

I am not understanding this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replot` calls the previous `plot` command and then adds another plot. In the previous plot command the variables haven't been replaced. When the `replot` calls the previous plot command, the last values of `xCol` and `yCol` are used for both plots!

You can either use two different variables:

```
xCol1 = 2; yCol1 = 3
plot '< stuff.pl' u xCol1:yCol1

xCol2 = 4; yCol2 = 5
replot '< stuff.pl' u xCol2:yCol2
```

or you can use macros, which are replaced

```
set macros
cols='2:3'
plot '< stuff.pl' u @cols

cols='4:5'
replot '< stuff.pl' u @cols
```

Comment: Once again thx for your great help on a Gnuplot-related topic @Christoph :)