# Using variable to define legend while looping

Tags: plot, gnuplot, legend

Relating to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000819/scaling-of-multiplot-while-using-variables-to-define-the-column) I build following Gnuplot-script (v4.6 patchlevel 3):

```
set macros
set term x11 1
plot '< stuff.pl' u 2:3 t "graph for variable 1" lw 2

do for [i=2:5]{

        var=system(sprintf("stuff.pl | awk -F'\t' 'NR == 1 {print $%f}'",2*i+1))
        print var

        xCol=2*i; yCol=2*i+1

        set term x11 1
        replot '< stuff.pl' u xCol:yCol t "graph for ".var lw 2
        pause 3
}
```

My aim was to use the different columns (which are written to `STDOUT` via the script **stuff.pl**) and plot them to one graph and use the names from the header to title the graphs. The output from **stuff.pl** looks like:

```
#Files  a    var1      b    var2      c    var3      d    var4      e    var5
5       1    0.231     0    1.426     3    1.624     0    0.227     9    5.322
```

I tried around a lot and with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12858693/2622293) I was able to get the definition of `var` shown above.

The `print var` shows the correct values **var1**, **var2**, ... but my legend isn't correctly. It once again seems that the variable `var` isn't  reset/updated when used in `replot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried around a bit, but couldn't get it to work either.

Here is a bit different proposal, which doesn't use `replot`, but does the interation within the `plot` command. The complete first line of the file is extracted with `head`, and the respective field is selected later with the `word` function:

```
set term x11 1
header = system('stuff.pl | head -1')
plot for [i=1:5] '< stuff.pl' using (column(2*i)):(column(2*i+1)) title 'graph for variable '.word(header, 2*i+1)
```

Comment: This works for my question but regarding further plot manipulation it's not the ultimate solution I guess. For example I am using `stats` to capture and adjust my `yrange`. Something like `stats for [i=1:5]` isn't working.

Comment: You are right, I still wanted to propose that :) I had problems with macros in the looping. Don't know if this is a bug, I'll investigate further. Regarding the `stats`, you can have that in a loop. I think the problem is with macros and/or replot. So the following should work: `max(x,y) = (x > y ? x : y); do for [i=1:5] { stats '< stuff.pl' using (column(2*i+1)) nooutput; if (i == 1) { ymax = STATS_max } else { ymax = max(STATS_max, ymax) }}`.